# Matrix class generalizing symmetry and skew-symmetry; does the following have a name?

Tags: matrices

Let $\mathbf X$ be a square (real, in my case) matrix of the form $\mathbf X= \mathbf T + a\mathbf T'$, where $\mathbf T$ is triangular. E.g, 
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 10 & 20 \\ 1 & 0 & 30 \\ 2 & 3 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

This class generalizes symmetry ($a=1$) and skew-symmetry ($a=-1$).  In my case, they are - like the example - a bit more special than the definition; the entries are nonnegative with the main diagonal zero. But the above definition is something I could imagine would have a name where I could search for properties.